# Why not make AJAX calls in React ES6 class constructor?

Tags: javascript, ajax, reactjs

The [React docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html#mounting-componentdidmount) say I should make AJAX calls to set the state in componentDidMount(), not the constructor. According to all the examples I have seen, this is how I should load data from the server:

```
constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {toDoItems: []};
}

componentDidMount() {
    loadToDoItems()
        .then(items => this.setState({toDoItems: items}));
}
```

Why not just load the server data in the constructor, like this?:

```
constructor() {
    super();
    loadToDoItems()
        .then(items => this.state = {toDoItems: items});
}
```

Comment: Why load data for a component that may never mount?

Comment: Why would the constructor be called if the component wouldn't be mounted?

Comment: It could be passed to another component but that component may only render it if a condition is met.

Comment: @JosephKriefall - why would you need a componentDidMount callback if all components always mounted as a result of being created?

Comment: So you can access the DOM

Comment: Another reason not to make AJAX calls in constructor: you don't know if it will succeed or how long it will take http://stackoverflow.com/a/29883895/2994322