# reactjs state is being lost between events

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a React component that's created dynamically, with data loaded into its state. This state is being cleared between click events, resulting in the `visible` info being lost (`undefined`). Where has it gone?

```
const React = require('react');
const ReactDOM = require('react-dom');

class App extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.nodesQuantity = 0;
    this.state = {roots: []};
  }

  nextId(me) {
    return me.nodesQuantity++;
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    var roots = [1,2,3].map(node => {
        let nextId = this.nextId(this);
        return <Node key={nextId} data={node} nextId={this.nextId} depth={0} god={this} />
    });
    this.setState({roots: roots});
  } 

  render() {
    return (
        <ul>{this.state.roots}</ul>
    )
  }
}

class Node extends React.Component{
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {data: this.props.data, childNodes: [], visible: true};
    this.toggleExpanded = this.toggleExpanded.bind(this);
  }

  toggleExpanded(event) {
    console.log(this.state.childNodes.length)
    let val={id:"asdf",label:"asdf"}

    if (this.state.childNodes.length > 0) {
        this.state.childNodes.forEach((childNode) => {
            childNode.setState({visible: !childNode.state.visible}) 
        });
    } else {        
        this.setState((oldState, props) => {
            let nextId = props.nextId(props.god);
            console.log(nextId);
            oldState.childNodes.push(<Node key={nextId} data={val} nextId={props.nextId} depth={props.depth+1} god={props.god} />);
        });     
    }       
    event.stopPropagation();
  }

  render() {
    return (
        <li onClick={this.toggleExpanded}>
            {this.state.data.id} ({this.state.data.label})
            <ul>{this.state.childNodes}</ul>
        </li>           
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('react')
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it. My main problem was a misunderstanding of react lifecycle.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29883895/525369), albeit a bit outdated, was quite useful in understanding my problem.

Also a bit switch was to store the Node as json and only build the nodes during `render` step. Updates are triggered with `setState` which pass through the `componentWillReceiveProps` method that updates the state of the node json and proceeds to `render`

Here's my solution: https://jsfiddle.net/n3ygz7uk/2/

Answer (score 2):

```
(oldState, props) => {
    let nextId = props.nextId(props.god);
    console.log(nextId);
    oldState.childNodes.push(<Node key={nextId} data={val} nextId={props.nextId} depth={props.depth+1} god={props.god} />);
                      }
```

doesn't return anything... possibly the source of your `undefined`.  You're also modifying previous state via push which is forbidden in the react docs:

> prevState is a reference to the previous state. It should not be
>   directly mutated. Instead, changes should be represented by building a
>   new object based on the input from prevState and props.

You ought to be doing something like:

```
return {childNodes:[...(oldState.childNodes)]}
```

Comment: yes, that's definitely cleaner. But I'm still having the problem of the state being lost. Have a look here (https://jsfiddle.net/n3ygz7uk/1/) when clicking the second time on a list item to hide it

Comment: ironically, when i click on the childNode, the `state` is populated correctly. It seems that just externally it's not visible / accessible?